# First zoom event removes center-transform

Tags: d3.js

I have a 'Radial Tidy Tree' like this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

I am trying to add zooming and panning, but I am not able to get both zooming and panning to work properly.

My code looks something like this:

```
var width = 1000,
    height = 800;

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select('.svg-container').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin')
    .call(zoom);

var g = svg.append("g").attr(
    "transform",
    "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ") scale(1)"
);

function zoomed() {
    g.attr(
      "transform",
      d3.event.transform
    );
}
```

When I drag or scroll for the very first time, **the *g* element jumps to the top left**. The very first *d3.event.transform* outputs this:

```
{k: 1, x: 0, y: 0}
```

If I zoom or pan after that, it works fine.

When I try this:

```
function zoomed() {
    var x = (width / 2) + d3.event.transform.x;
    var y = (height / 2) + d3.event.transform.y;

    g.attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" + x + "," + y + ") scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")"
    );
}
```

the *g* element does not jump to the top left and panning works fine, but the zooming does not zoom based on the mouse position (only works correctly when the mouse is in the top left corner).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `d3` stores an elements zoom on the element [itself](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoomTransform), it needs to know about all transforms that'll be part of the zoom.  In your case, you've set the initial position via a `.attr` call (and not the zoom), so `d3` doesn't know about it.  To set it via the zoom instead do:

```
var width = 1000,
    height = 800;

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select('.svg-container').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin')
    .call(zoom);

var g = svg.append("g");

// set initial position via zoom
svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(width/2, height/2));

function zoomed() {
    g.attr(
      "transform",
      d3.event.transform
    );
}
```

Working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fz1j0viPwkjXqOypOUeK?p=preview).