# zoom jumps when using mouse after zoom In/out

Tags: d3.js

I am Trying to display my full svg tree within the display in a center view.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
            svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    })).on("dblclick.zoom", null)
   .attr("width", "1000")
   .attr("height",590)
   .append("g")
svg.attr("transform",function(d) {
   return "translate(" + 450 + "," + svgHeight + ") scale(" + scale + ")";
} );
```

I am adjusting the scale and height properties of the transform depends on the number of nodes, actually its working fine.

The problem is when I am trying to zoom in/out on the tree for the first time , its not zooming the focused node.

This occurs only when I am doing zoom for first time, from second time its zooming the pointing node.

This is what I tried so far  : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gowtham14io/pen/OJNZJBx?editors=1010)

Comment: [possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50699286/12223898). zoom has its own `transform` instead of the `(450, svgHeight)` you set.

Comment: Hi @soundquiet thanks for your reply. I need to display my tree  in center of  the screen.So I used it for the tree. By the way in my code  zoom is constructed with its own translate properties, you can see that in 3rd line of the code

Comment: the 3rd line works after zoom happens, not the initial transform. Is this what you want? [demo](https://codepen.io/soundquiet/pen/oNxdLyX?editors=1010)

Comment: @soundquiet - it looks like your demo fixes the zoom issue, but panning now produces weird, shaking behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drawback of the otherwise solid solution @soundquiet posted is that it disrupts panning behaviour, leading to some sort of rapid shifting of the nodes.

A simpler, and more robust solution is shown below. I just wrap the `g`-element inside another `g` element called `zoomContainer` and call all zoom behaviour on that instead.

```js
var treeData = {
  "name": "Share point Server 2019",
  "id": "a093F0000078Id5QAE",
  "children": [{
    "name": "is extended by",
    "level": "sub node",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Share point Server 2019",
      "id": "a093F0000078Id5QAE"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "manages",
    "level": "sub node",
    "children": [{
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }, {
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }, {
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }, {
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }, {
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }, {
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }, {
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }, {
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }, {
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }, {
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }, {
      "name": "HPE ProLiant ML350 Tower",
      "id": "a093F0000078IcHQAU"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "is operated by",
    "level": "sub node",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Power point SH-20",
      "id": "a093F00000794ZWQAY"
    }]
  }]
};
var scale = 1,
  svgHeight = 200,
  nodeCount = 13;;
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 90,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 90
  },
  width = window.outerWidth,
  height = window.outerHeight;
var focused = false;
console.log('scale', scale)
var zoomContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
    zoomContainer.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  })).on("dblclick.zoom", null)
  .attr("width", "1000")
  .attr("height", 590)
  .append("g")

var svg = zoomContainer
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" +
      (450) + "," + (svgHeight) + ") scale(" + scale + ")";
  });

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;
// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
  return d.children;
});
root.x0 = height;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
if (typeof collapse === 'undefined')
  root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
    links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);
  let left = root;
  let right = root;
  var dx = ((nodeCount * 18) / 1000);
  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d, index) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
    d.x = d.x * ((nodeCount * 18) / 1000);

  });
  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (source.y0) + "," + (source.x0) + ")";
    })
    .on('click', d => {
      // d3.event.preventDefault();

      component.set("v.nodeName", d.data.name);
    })
    .on("dblclick", click);


  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', 1e-6)
    .style('stroke', 'steelblue')
    .style('stroke-width', '3px');

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (d.y) + "," + (d.x) + ")";
    });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 3)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (source.y) + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style('fill', "none")
    .style('stroke', "#ccc")
    .style('stroke-width', "2px")
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      }
      return diagonal(o, o)
    });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return diagonal(d, d.parent)
    });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      }
      return diagonal(o, o)
    })
    .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {
    var path = "M" + d.y + "," + d.x +
      "C" + (d.y + s.y) / 2 + "," + d.x +
      " " + (d.y + s.y) / 2 + "," + s.x +
      " " + s.y + "," + s.x;

    return path;
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div style="background:white" id="body"></div>
```

Comment: Hi ,We have an zooming issue with the same example.Zooming is applying to full svg. so if we scroll in empty places its zooming. so the original tree is going out of the focus. so we just want to restrict the zoom on tree only.Can you please help me